# AzureML: experiment working for a subset and not for the whole dataset

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

some times ago I had written a code in AzureML meeting "out of memory" issues. So I tried to split the code in three different codes and that partially worked. It remains a part that (I think) is affected by memory issues too.

I have created an experiment that I have published in this [link](http://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/TextMining-sample-NA-v1-1).

There is a module that considers only a sample of my dataset, and it does work. This means that the code is supposed to work correctly. If you remove the sampling code (the second module starting from the top)

[image]

and you connect directly the original dataset you have the following situation

[image]

producing the following error:

[image]

Does someone have some way to understand where Azure crashes?

Thanks you,

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for publishing the example -- this really helped to understand the issue. I suspect that you want to modify the `gsub()` calls in your script by adding the argument "`fixed=TRUE`" to each. (The documentation for this function is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html).)

What appears to have happened is that somewhere in your full dataset -- but not in the subsampled dataset -- there is some text that winds up being included in `df[i, "names"]` as "`(art.`".  Your script pads this into "`\\b(art.\\b`". The `gsub()` function tries to interpret this as a regular expression instead of a simple string, then throws an error because it is not a valid regular expression: it contains an opening parenthesis but no closing parenthesis. I believe that you actually did not want `gsub()` to interpret the input as a regular expression in the first place, and specifying `gsub(..., fixed=TRUE)` will correct that.

I believe the reason why this error disappears when you add the sample/partition module is because, by chance, the problematic input value was dropped on subsampling. I do not think it is an issue of available resources on Azure ML. (Caveat: I cannot confirm the fix works yet; I made the suggested update and started running the experiment, but it has not yet completed successfully.)

Comment: Thanks Mewahl! Nevertheless, I don't understand why the same code does work running out od AzureML (on RStudio for example I haven't met such a problem). Anyways, I have used 'myWord <- paste0("\\b",df[i,"names"],"\\b")' because I needed that only entire words were substituted... so I actually need the regular expression.

Comment: Anyways, for now I have tried with file_polarizzato[,column] <- gsub("(art.","",file_polarizzato[,column]) that should remove at least "that" issue. I'll see in 20 hours if I have solved the issue....!!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that -- you're right that a regular expression is needed if you'd like to accommodate all forms of word boundaries. (I had simply replaced the "\b"s with spaces; I misunderstood the use of the symbol.) I worry, though, that there are other cases besides "(art." where punctuation in df$names results in an unintended regular expression: some could cause unintended matching behavior even without throwing errors. Is it possible, for your use case, to replace problematic punctuation with spaces or otherwise remove it?

Comment: Consider that I had previously removed punctuations and parentheses (before adding the dataset to AzureML) so I am a little surprised that I've found one. Anyways, I'm waiting to see if the "(art." could be the only one..!

Comment: Ok, I've done a check and the file I had uploaded actually had parentheses. I have removed them and "run" the code... all I can do is hope! :)

Comment: My runs still crash. Have you solved somehow @mewahl?